# Execution of a OS command from a Python daemon

Tags: python, bash, operating-system, command, handler

I've got a daemon.py with a callback. How should I make the handler function execute a OS command?

Comment: It would help if you could provide some code or other context for this question.  With so little information the only answer is subprocess.Popen.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

when i learned Python some time ago, I used:

```
import os
os.system('ls -lt')
```

but it seems like in Python 3.x, the recommended use is [commands](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html) or [os.popen()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen)

Comment: don't use os.system. It's recommended to use subprocess.Popen instead.